# Making a practice window in vscode, window immediately closes

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, error-handling, window

Using Python 3.8.2

I'm attempting to create a simple practice window in vscode on MacOS (beginner obviously):

```
print("Practice using tkinter module to make a window:")

from tkinter import *  
root = Tk()
master = Frame(root,borderwidth = 5, width = 500, height = 500)
master.pack
```

This results in a window opening in the background for a split second and then closing. Is there something in my code that's preventing the window from staying open?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The way VS Code works is that it runs the program externally, outside of VS Code.

So when you run it, it executes the code, but because it is the simple Python executer doing it, it will exit as soon as it is finished.

There are two options to solve this.

- Either use a different IDE (VS and VS Code both don't support easily
  running the code you've written within them, instead only allowing
  you to run individual statements in a shell or running it externally)
  or...
- You could `import pdb` and add `pdb.set_trace()` at the end of your
  code to allow you to investigate variables with `p [expression or

  variable name]` or do whatever else you like using debug instead of
  shell commands. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Hope this helps!